# JAVAFX Stage changes its size on change in Scene. Or thats what I think

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, javafx-11

Whenever I switch Scenes the UI gets cropped at this weird angle. It was happening in my actual project but there were too many components to go through, so I decided to make a dummy one. The actual project VBox as root, here it is AnchorPane. Results are exactly the same.

Intended UI : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cPYC.jpg)

Change to scene2 : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl2dX.jpg)

Switch back to scene1 : [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfgSl.jpg)

Main.java
   `

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(true);

    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
}`
```

sample.fxml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadScene2" text="Go to Scene 2" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

scene2.fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Scene2">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadScene2" text="Go to scene 1" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java:

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
private AnchorPane root;
@FXML
private void loadScene2() throws IOException {
    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene2.fxml"));
    root.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}
```

}

Scene2.java:

```
public class Scene2 {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;
    @FXML
    private void loadScene2() throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        root.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is you're never actually unloading your previous anchor pain as you posted you are calling

```
root.getChildren()
```

this means that you are just setting the content of your sample anchor pane to another anchor pane nesting them leading to this weird behavior.

Try this instead and see if it works

```
Parent parent = root.getParent();
parent.getChildren().remove(root);
parent.getChildren().add(pane);
```

This should clear up your problem let me know if that fixes it